# Why isn't my command buffer in the right state?

Tags: vulkan

I have made a command pool that does not have the VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT flag set. I submit command buffers, and when those command buffers are completed I reset the pool. I keep the command buffer around, and I get it again, and I begin recording, with the VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT. The validation layer gives me this error:

> [VULKAN][INFO] Vulkan validation layer callback: Validation Error: [
> VUID-vkBeginCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00050 ] Object 0: handle =
> 0x20db70f20c0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; Object 1: handle
> = 0xcb1c7c000000001b, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_POOL; | MessageID = 0xb24f00f5 | Call to vkBeginCommandBuffer() on VkCommandBuffer 0x20db70f20c0[] attempts to implicitly reset cmdBuffer created from
> VkCommandPool 0xcb1c7c000000001b[] that does NOT have the
> VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT bit set. The Vulkan
> spec states: If commandBuffer was allocated from a VkCommandPool which
> did not have the VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT flag
> set, commandBuffer must be in the initial state

Now, isn't it in the initial state after I reset the pool?

Comment: "*Now, isn't it in the initial state after I reset the pool?*" Did you actually reset the pool? Also, how do you know those CBs have completed? Note that resetting a pool that creates a secondary CB while that secondary CB has been recorded into some other primary CB will cause the primary CB to become invalid.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes I reset it. And I only reset when the signal value was set for the timeline semaphore that was given when I submitted the batches. When a queue submission's highest timeline semaphore signal value has been signalled I return all the command buffers to the pool, and all of them have been returned then I reset the pool.

Comment: @NicolBolas Why's it saying I'm implicitly resetting the command buffer by calling vkbegincommandbuffer? When does that happen?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well I might just set the VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT I guess to get rid of the warning, I don't know.

Comment: Well, there are two possibilities: 1) there is a bug in the validation layer, or 2) your code is doing something you don't think it's doing. We don't have your code, so there's no way to verify either.